# Will app be rejected if we have different tabs on different screens - iphone

Tags: iphone, app-store

My application has a following requirement.

1) First screen has two tabs.

2) From the first tab I need to navigate to other screen which will contain 3 tabs.

like wise each screen is going to have different tabs (different tab icon and text)
and so on.

To handle this I am using UITabBarController inside UINavigationController. (So I have only one NavigationController).

I know apple recommends the other way.

Please suggest if application will be rejected by apple?
And also is there any other approach to handle this. 
Please not I don't want to use Segments and want to use tab (This is the clients requirement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no man it wont be rejected . please go through the  Bonjour, Kimberly Clark App in App store

Comment: agreed - take a look at twitter.app.  It displays different tabs based on which view in the nav stack the user is viewing. it shouldn't get rejected.

Answer (score 1):

It will probably be rejected, but more importantly, it will be confusing to everyone who uses it because nowhere else do tab bars work this way. When tab bars exist, they are the primary mode of navigation across the application, with the possible exception of tab bars that appear in modal views (like the iPod picking view you can bring up).

If your client is requiring this, your client is dooming the application to being hard to use and to be rejected. With this evidence, you should be able to convince them.

Answer (score 0):

Apple is now where forcing to follow there standards **only**.

Either you should follow the navigation Standards set by Apple.

If you wanna come up with something by your own, then it should be better than standard ways suggested by Apple. There are many applications available which have come with their own way of navigation, but again it should be simple, different is okay, but simplicity is important.

See this for example [example](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/the-best-iphone-apps/20/)

also this [one](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/the-best-iphone-apps/3/)